# Вычислить бесконечную сумму с заданной точностью C++

Tags: c++, математика

Всем привет, при решении задачи возникли трудности: не могу понять где допущена ошибка. Помогите пожалуйста ее исправить. И правильно ли я ее решаю?

Задание:
Вычислить бесконечную сумму S с точностью ε.
Считать, что требуемая точность достигнута, если значение
очередного слагаемого по модулю меньше заданного ε (это и все
последующие слагаемые можно не учитывать). Определить и вывести
количество слагаемых найденной суммы, учтенных при расчете.
Значение суммы выводить с точностью до 8 знаков в дробной части.
Если ни один из слагаемых не был учтен, то выдать об этом сообщение.
Внимание! Для нахождения степени числа не использовать
стандартных функций, а вычислять его самостоятельно с помощью
оператора цикла. Для вычисления факториала числа применить цикл for.
Ограничения: x, ε – действительные числа (x ≠ 0, ε > 0),
 – целое число ( || < 106).
По формуле:
[image]

Мое решение(основные ф-и):

```
double factorial(int n) { // Функция для вычисления факториала числа
    double fact = 1;
    for (int i = 1; i <= n; i++) {
        fact *= i;
    }
    return fact;
}

double valueA(int k) {
    if (k % 2 == 0) {
        return -1; // Для четных k
    }
    else {
        return factorial(k); // Для нечетных k
    }
}

// Функция для вычисления бесконечной суммы

double infinite_sum(double x, double e, int a) {
    double sum = 0;
    double term;
    int k = 1;

    do {
        term = sin(k * x) / k * valueA(a);
        sum += term;
        k++;
    } while (abs(term) >= e);

    if (k == 1) {
        cout << "Ни одно из слагаемых не было учтено.";
        return 0;
    }
    else {
        cout << endl;
        cout << "Сумма равна " << fixed << setprecision(8) << sum << endl; // устанавливаем точность вывода до 8 знаков после запятой 
        cout << endl;
        cout << "Количество учтенных слагаемых равно " << k - 1 << endl;
        return sum;
    }
}
```

Comment: *Меня терзают смутные сомнения* (с), что даже при a = 106 (не 10⁶) значение a! будет таким большим, что говорить о точности в 8 знаков после запятой будет сверхнаивностью... Разве что x будет равно π или что-то вроде того... :) Кстати, у вас valueA вычисляет явно не то, что написано в условии.

Comment: а какая у вас ошибка в итоге появляется? Что не так?

Comment: Неправильно считает, проверил по формуле при определенных значениях в онлайн калькуляторе ответ 1 , а в программе другой.

Comment: ничего страшного в 106! нет. точности double хватит с запасом. вижу у вас ошибку в алгоритме подсчете сумм. вы предполагаете, что если одно слагаемое равно точности, то следующее уж точно его будет меньше. хотя последовательность у вас не монотонная.

Comment: @Velmar Ваша задача явно неправильно поставлена. Слагаемые становятся по модулю заведомо меньше eps, когда `k>a!/eps` - а это невероятное число итераций

Comment: @MBo Условие "*Считать, что требуемая точность достигнута, если значение очередного слагаемого по модулю меньше заданного ε*" вообще неверное. Ведь по нему ряд может закончиться при конкретном везучем `sin(kx)/k`, при том что даже следующий такой член будет выпадать из условия, не говоря уж об a!...

Comment: @Harry Именно, потому я и говорил о "заведомо меньше". Однако задание скопировано из методички, значит, кто-то писал такую методичку...

Comment: @MBo Забавно, что ряд, оказывается, суммируется в аналитике... \frac{1}{4} i \left(2 a \tanh ^{-1}\left(e^{-i x}\right)-2 a \tanh ^{-1}\left(e^{i x}\right)+\log \left(1-e^{-2 i x}\right)-\log \left(1-e^{2 i x}\right)\right)

Comment: @Harry Хм. Может, кто увидел в справочнике рядов аналитическое выражение, и ничтоже сумняшеся дал ряд как упражнение по методам вычислений?

Comment: @MBo Ну я даю... Блин. Это ж обычный простейший ряд Фурье...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
#include <math.h>
#include <clocale>
#include <iomanip>
#include <iostream>

double fact(int n) {
    double res = 1;
    for (int i = 2; i <= n; ++i)
        res *= i;
    return res;
}

void infinite_sum(double x, double e, int a, int& k, double& sum) {
    k = 1;
    sum = 0;

    double x_k = x, b = fact(a);
    double val = b * std::sin(x);

    while((val > 0? val : -val) >= e) {
        sum += val;
        val = std::sin(x_k += x) / ++k;
        val = k & 1? b * val : -val;
    }
    --k;
}

double get_a_k(double x, double b, int k) {
    double res = std::sin(k * x) / k;
    res = k & 1? b * res : -res;
    return res;
}

int main()
{
    std::setlocale(LC_ALL, "rus");

    const int N = 6;
    const double X = 0.5, E = 0.001;
    
    int k;
    double sum;
    (void) infinite_sum(X, E, N, k, sum);
    
    if(!k)
        std::cout << "Ни одно из слагаемых не было учтено.";
    else {
        std::cout << "Сумма: " << std::fixed << std::setprecision(8) << sum << '\n';
        std::cout << "Количество учтенных cлагаемых: " << k << '\n';

        ++k;
        double val, nsum = 0, b = fact(N);
        for(int i = 1; i <= k; ++i) {
            std::cout << "a(" << i << ") = " << (val = get_a_k(X, b, i)) << "; ";
            std::cout << "s(" << i << ") = " << (nsum += val) << ";\n";
        }

    }
    return 0;
}
```

Результат:

```
Сумма: 581.93557436
Количество учтенных cлагаемых: 43
a(1) = 345.18638780; s(1) = 345.18638780;
a(2) = -0.42073549; s(2) = 344.76565230;
a(3) = 239.39879678; s(3) = 584.16444909;
a(4) = -0.22732436; s(4) = 583.93712473;
a(5) = 86.17998875; s(5) = 670.11711348;
a(6) = -0.02352000; s(6) = 670.09359348;
a(7) = -36.08056056; s(7) = 634.01303292;
a(8) = 0.09460031; s(8) = 634.10763323;
a(9) = -78.20240941; s(9) = 555.90522382;
a(10) = 0.09589243; s(10) = 556.00111624;
a(11) = -46.18082131; s(11) = 509.82029493;
a(12) = 0.02328462; s(12) = 509.84357956;
a(13) = 11.91433780; s(13) = 521.75791736;
a(14) = -0.04692761; s(14) = 521.71098975;
a(15) = 45.02399889; s(15) = 566.73498863;
a(16) = -0.06183489; s(16) = 566.67315374;
a(17) = 33.81827771; s(17) = 600.49143145;
a(18) = -0.02289547; s(18) = 600.46853598;
a(19) = -2.84783193; s(19) = 597.62070405;
a(20) = 0.02720106; s(20) = 597.64790510;
a(21) = -30.16099748; s(21) = 567.48690762;
a(22) = 0.04545410; s(22) = 567.53236172;
a(23) = -27.40545938; s(23) = 540.12690234;
a(24) = 0.02235720; s(24) = 540.14925954;
a(25) = -1.91007064; s(25) = 538.23918890;
a(26) = -0.01616027; s(26) = 538.22302863;
a(27) = 21.43425137; s(27) = 559.65728000;
a(28) = -0.03537883; s(28) = 559.62190117;
a(29) = 23.21118759; s(29) = 582.83308875;
a(30) = -0.02167626; s(30) = 582.81141249;
a(31) = 4.79537377; s(31) = 587.60678627;
a(32) = 0.00899698; s(32) = 587.61578325;
a(33) = -15.52986202; s(33) = 572.08592123;
a(34) = 0.02827640; s(34) = 572.11419763;
a(35) = -20.07002068; s(35) = 552.04417694;
a(36) = 0.02086076; s(36) = 552.06503770;
a(37) = -6.66448771; s(37) = 545.40054999;
a(38) = -0.00394414; s(38) = 545.39660585;
a(39) = 11.17919759; s(39) = 556.57580345;
a(40) = -0.02282363; s(40) = 556.55297982;
a(41) = 17.50530370; s(41) = 574.05828352;
a(42) = -0.01992037; s(42) = 574.03836315;
a(43) = 7.89721121; s(43) = 581.93557436;
a(44) = 0.00020117; s(44) = 581.93577553;
```

### Вычисления с mathforyou.net/online/calculus/series/sum

S(1) = 720*sin(0.5) = 345,18638779
[image: введите сюда описание изображения][image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Итого: S = S(1) + S(2, 43) = 345.18638779 + 236.74918656 = 581,93557435

Comment: Здравствуйте, если я все верно ввел в калькулятор, формула такая(в формуле использую z, вместо k, так как к нету) sin(z*0.5)/z*720=950.973, сумма из вашей кода 581.93... . Если я где-то допустил ошибку поправьте, спасибо что пытаетесь помочь.

Comment: @Velmar Нет, формула неправильная. Вы забыли про то, что значение b изменяется в зависимости от чётности k, т.е. по сути у нас имеется две формулы s(k) = 720*sin(kx)/k, при нечётных значениях k, и s(k) = -sin(kx)/k, при чётных k... Попробуёте в дебагере пройтись пошагово по коду и посмотреть, как изменяется значение term, и вам всё станет понятно...

Comment: Кстати, я сейчас пересмотрел ваш код, у вас там всё +- правильно, единственное после цикла нужно --k добавить. Только он не очень оптимальный, особенно функция valueA, т.к. по сути на каждой итерации цикла вы вычисляете факториал заново, и умножение k*x можно заменить сложением, что намного быстрее, просто на каждой итерации цикла к уже сохранённому предыдущему значению прибавляется x, и k%2 можно заменить на k&1

Comment: Я поэтому и написал формулы вычисления которую вводил в калькуляторе, как в примере что я проверяю именно нечетное, поэтому и подставил факториал 6. +- правильно, хорошо, спасибо.

Comment: @Velmar Я не очень понял, что именно вы имеете ввиду, но если вы хотите считать суммы чётных и нечётных элементов раздельно, то вам  нужно будте в калькуляторе ещё казать шаг, т.е. для чётных: k0 = 2, kn = 42, шаг = 2; для нечётных: k0 = 1, kn = 43, шаг = 2; Ну и, естественно, потом их сложить.

Comment: Кстати, верное значение для этих параметров — 564.951

Comment: Возможно я что-то не так проверяю, как вы проверяли? Я имел ввиду что я могу ввести в калькулятор 1 значение и проверить, или с четным или нет, в коде x = 0.5 значит нечетное, значит считаем факториал, то есть если бы я поставил четное я бы умножал на -1. Пример 1 нечетное- sin(z*0.5)/z*720, 2- четное sin(z*2)/z*-1 = -0.57080. Калькулятор: https://mathforyou.net/online/calculus/series/sum/

Comment: @Velmar S_чёт = sum{k = 1, 21}( -sin(2kx)/2k );  S_нчёт = sum{k = 0, 21}( a! * sin((2k+1)*x)/(2k+1) ); В нашем случае получется(k поменяем на z):   S_чёт = sum{z = 1, 21}( -sin(2 * z * 0.5)/(2z) ) = sum{z = 1, 21}( -sin(z)/(2z) ) = -0.55621747; S_нчёт = sum{z = 0, 21}( 720*sin((2*z+1)*0.5)/(2z+1) ) = sum{z = 0, 21}( 720*sin(2*z*0.5 + 0.5)/(2z+1) ) = sum{z = 0, 21}( 720*sin(z + 0.5)/(2z+1) ) = 582.49179183; S = S_чёт + S_нчёт = 582.49179183 - 0.55621747 = 581,93557436. ЧТД

Comment: @Velmar Я подкоректировал ответ, там формулы более понятно выглядят...

Comment: @Harry Не знаю, вот только что проверил ответ, всё совпадает до последнеё цифры. Как вы получили 564.951???

Comment: Я о **правильном** с точки зрения математики, а не о вашем подсчете. Сама постановка задачи, а особенно условие прекращения счета — с точки зрения математики — несусветная глупость. 40 членов — ни о чем!

Comment: @Harry А, вы имеете ввиду на бесконечности. Ну а постановка задачи такая, чтобы можно было удобно выдти из цикла, наткнулись на число меньшее заданого и досвидания...

Comment: А толку? Возьмите X=1.0472 "Удобный" выход из цикла дает 498.6, точное значение — 565.2. Ошибка в 12%. Ага, как же... `E = 0.001;` *Это вот не заливная... эээ... не задача, это стрихнин какой-то!* Просто даже интересно, где это такие долб... преподы работают?

Comment: Подскажите(формулу), а в калькуляторе это можно как-то записать чтобы вывело на итог S = 581,93557435?

Comment: @Velmar Нет. Вы либо можете отдельно посчитать сумму всех чётных (-0.55, вроде) и сумму всех нечётных (около 582) и их сложить, либо как я сделал S(1) + S(2, 43). Там в формуле, выражение, в знаменателе которого стоит 2z+1, отвечает за нечётные элементы, а 2z за чётные соответственно, ну и z у нас будет в пределах от 1 до 21 включительно.

Comment: Там проблема в том, что если брать отдельно суммы чётных и нечётных, то у нечётных z будет идти от 0 (т.к. 2z+1 = 2*0+1 = 1), а у чётных от единицы, т.к. 2z стоит в значенателе, а даже если не учитывать, что деление на нуль невозможно и взять предел, то там всё равно ответ улетит в бесконечность. Единственное, вы можете попробовать найти такой калькулятор, который бы поддерживал пользователькие функции в формуле, и определить b(z)=720 - н/ч, -1 ч. Тогда вы можете спокойно вводить ту формулу, которая у вас дана в условие. Может, в desmos-e такое поддерживается, но я не уверен, поищите...